# ¿Es correcto decir «muy otra» como sinónimo de «muy distinta» en «La realidad es muy otra»?

Tags: gramática

Hace dos minutos he escuchado a una locutora de radio pronunciar la siguiente oración (más o menos):

> Se supone que, desde 2008, los gobiernos han ido endureciendo los controles sobre las grandes compañías, pero **la realidad es muy otra**.

Yo había oído expresiones como *«la realidad es otra»* y *«la realidad es muy distinta»*, ambas con un significado similar. Pero esto de «muy otra» no acaba de cuadrarme.

¿Es correcto decir «muy otra» como sinónimo de «muy distinta»?

Comment: Yo si he oído eso más veces, lo que no sé es si es correcto o no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el DLE aparece la locución *ser alguien o algo muy otro* y significa que muestra gran diferencia, así que parece ser que es una expresión correcta.

> [**ser** alguien o algo **muy otro**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xe5Brrm#A6LXfxl)
>
> **1.** loc. verb. coloq. Mostrar gran mudanza o diferencia.

En el ejemplo que propones se dice que lo que ocurre en realidad es muy distinto de lo que dice la afirmación anterior y podría cambiarse perfectamente por la expresión la «realidad es muy distinta» que nombras en la pregunta.

Comment: Yo había buscado en *otro* y no me salía nada. No sé cual será el criterio para meter las locuciones en una palabra o en otra.

Answer (score 6):

Habría una diferencia de grado. En general "distinto" implica que algo no es igual, mientras que "otro" hace referencia a que es diferente, o incluso opuesto.

Uno puede decir que algo es *distinto* sin que por ello se considere que es mucha la diferencia. Que algo sea *otro* implica que la diferencia es tal que ni siquiera es comparable, porque es lo opuesto.

En consecuencia, uno puede decir que algo es *distinto*, *muy distinto*, *ligeramente distinto*, *algo distinto*, etc. Pues la palabra admite graduaciones. En cambio la palabra *otro* inmediatamente implica que es casi opuesto, por ello no hay graduaciones.

Comment: Estoy completamente de acuerdo sin embargo la respuesta dice _"otro hace referencia a que es diferente"_ pero _diferente_ es sinónimo de _distinto_, o sea que por transitividad _otro_ es también sinónimo de _distinto_ .Lo malo es que no se me ocurre como definirlo de una mejor manera. Pero definitivamente "otro" es un calificativo absoluto que no acepta graduaciones. +1

Comment: Que no es correcto, eso.  @DGaleano - Lo que capté de la respuesta es que "otro" es una especie de *toggle* (variable binaria). // walen, esto me hace pensar en otra frase de radiolocutor: "... el mas grande en el mundo y sus alrededores."

Comment: Del comentario anterior me parece inferir que para @aparente001 "muy otra" es correcto (¿entendí bien?). Pues a mi me suena terrible y como dice Santiago "otro" no debería tener grados. Mi problema está es en la forma de argumentar de la respuesta (distinto=diferente=otro)

Comment: @DGaleano - No, no.  Digo "no es correcto."  Traté de aclara para walen.